# Make sticky header on mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I'm using mat-tab-group and I want the tab headers to be fixed when I scroll down to the content. So, I fixed the height of tab content. I'm able to scroll through the content with fixed header. But, then I see two scroll bars on the page which is weird. Is there any other way that I can fix the tab headers while scrolling through the content? Attaching the snippet:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
    <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 50%">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Tab 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 3">Tab 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[image]

**[Edit]: I'm more of looking to make header of mat-tab fixed. So, is there any straight forward way to do it instead of fixing height in styles?**

Comment: You can add style to the body of that page like <body style="overflow:hidden;">your code here</body>

Comment: @Shubham Is that a good idea? Because, keeping overflow hidden on body will reflect on whole application in angular.

Answer (score 11):

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Content 1"> Content </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Content 2"> Content </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Content 3"> Content </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**app.component.scss**

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-header {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000; 
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* macOS/iOS Safari */    
}
```

Comment: For Angular Material v15+ you have to use '.mat-**mdc**-tab-header' or 'mat-tab-header' (so no dot).

Comment: the css class names have been changed since, instead of `.mat-tab-header` you can use `.mdc-mat-tab-header` or the html tag directly `::ng-deep mat-tab-header { ..`

Answer (score 0):

Change `overflow` style, like:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: visible; height: 50%">
```

So, horizontal scroll will be visible only if needed, and the vertical won't appear.